# How to add additional file/folder in Netbeans native packaging for Java SE application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ant, inno-setup

I am trying to make an EXE installer of my Java Swing application following instructions found here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html

my dist folder structure is like this :

```
-> dist
   -> lib
   -> application.jar
   -> config folder //additional folder
   -> another additional folder //additional folder
```

Those two additional folder listed above gets ignored after deploying native packaging. I want to add those two inside /app folder and keep the folder structure like below:

```
-> app
   -> lib
   -> config folder //additional folder
   -> another additional folder //additional folder
   -> application.jar
   -> package.cfg
-> runtime
   -> jre
-> applcation.exe
-> application.ico
-> unins000.dat
-> unins000.exe
```

I am using ant builder and inno setup for the purpose.

After trying for last few hours I decided to post it here for help. Anything towards the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans Java (JavaFX) Native Packaging with additional files and folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073292/netbeans-java-javafx-native-packaging-with-additional-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 0):

If you uses an iss script to build your installer, you can just add a new line to the script like this in the Files section:

```
[Files]
Source: "config\*"; DestDir: "{app}\config"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "additional\*"; DestDir: "{app}\additional"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

This should exist in the Netbeans native packaging as well. It seems to me that the sources tab might have the same effect.

Or you can [try this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25306349/4711547), but this still requires work outside netbeans.

Comment: No, I am not using any iss script and didn't find any file inside netbeans project where I can add those source lines.